# extract value from a # hash

Tags: python, flask, auth0

I'm trying to get auth0 to work but when I run the request I get the token after the #.  How do I get the access token from this url?

```
https://dcadventuresonline.com/callback#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6InNfaGNudlJleTMyWEFhVExoekhOQiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2RjYWR2ZW50dXJlc29ubGluZS51cy5hdXRoMC5jb20vIiwic3ViIjoiZ29v
```

I can run a split on the = but I can't figure out how to get the FULL url.  When I run request.url it cuts off everything after the #

Answer (score 0):

`urllib.parse.urldefrag` lets you extract the fragment that contains the token. You can then use `str.split` to extract the token.

```
>>> url = "https://dcadventuresonline.com/callback#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6InNfaGNudlJleTMyWEFhVExoekhOQiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2RjYWR2ZW50dXJlc29ubGluZS51cy5hdXRoMC5jb20vIiwic3ViIjoiZ29v"
>>> from urllib.parse import urldefrag
>>> url, fragment = urldefrag(url)
>>> token = fragment.split("=")[1]
```

Comment: the problem is that the url is only in the browser, not on the server.  how do i retrieve the full url within flask

Comment: What code, exactly, are you running that cuts anything?